# Cannot delete Hotmail account from Evolution

Tags: evolution, online-accounts

I had a Hotmail account set up in my Ubuntu online accounts. After upgrading to 15.04 (I believe, but maybe it happened earlier), that account somehow became corrupt - and now in fact there is no more option to add a Hotmail account in UOA. Anyhow, I managed to delete the account by editing the UOA database directly (in .conf/libaccounts-glib).

However, now I am stuck with a Hotmail account I can't access in Evolution. I tried removing all traces of it manually (erasing all I could find with a reference to it in .conf/evolution and in .local/share/evolution), but it's still there, but Evolution won't let me access it, telling me that Hotmail does not use 0auth2 or something of the sort.

I did re-install from within Evolution a new copy of my Hotmail account, and that one is working fine, so the problem is not with Hotmail as such.

Let me know what I can do,

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: Nevermind. I simply rebooted my computer and the old, non-working Hotmail account disappeared.

Comment: I have found that Evolution is a bit funny about adding or removing some types of account.  It is also very hard to exit Evolution and get all parts of it to close.  If you ever add or remove account but don't see it appear or disappear, it is worth trying logging out and back in again (or rebooting).